# Aggregate over top hits ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents are structured in the following way:

```
{
   "chefInfo": {
      "id": int,
      "employed": String
      ... Some more recipe information ...
   }
   "recipe": {
      ... Some recipe information ...
   }
}
```

If a chef has multiple recipes, the nested `chefInfo` block will be identical in each document. My problem is that I want to do an aggregation of a field in the `chefInfo` part of the document. However, this doesn't take into account for the fact that the `chefInfo` block is a duplicate.

So, if the chef with the id of 1 is on 5 recipes and I am aggregating on the `employed` field then this particular chef, will represent 5 of the counts in the aggregation, whereas, I want them to only count a single one.

I thought about doing a `top_hits` aggregation on the chef_id and then I wanted to do a sub-aggregation over all of the buckets but I can't work out how to do the counts over the results of all the buckets.

Is it possible what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For elastic every document in itself is unique. In your case you want to define uniqueness based on a different field, here `chefInfo.id`. To find unique count based on this field you have to make use of [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html).

You can apply the aggregation as below:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "employed": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "chefInfo"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "employed": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "chefInfo.employed.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "employed_unique": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "chefInfo.id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the result `employed_unique` give you the expected count.

Comment: Also know that if `chefInfo.id` has a high cardinality, the [counts may be approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate)